# Migrate Contentful asyncData to Nuxt 3 script setup format

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, contentful, vue-script-setup

I'm pretty new to using vue composition API and still not sure on how to migrate things over from options API.

I'm using nuxt and contentful and have pulled the below from [contentful's docs](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/integrate-contentful-with-vue-and-nuxt/) but need help to put this in a suitable format for script setup.

```js
import { createClient } from "~/plugins/contentful";
const client = createClient();

export default {
  // 'env' is available in the context object
  asyncData({ env }) {
    return Promise.all([
      // fetch all blog posts sorted by creation date
      client.getEntries({
        content_type: env.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID,
        order: "sys.createdAt",
      }),
    ])
      .then(([entries]) => {
        // return data that should be available in the template
        return {
          posts: entries.items,
        };
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  },

};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```html
<script setup>
import { createClient } from "~/plugins/contentful"
const client = createClient()

const { data, refresh /* ... */ } = await useAsyncData(() => {
  return Promise.all([
    // fetch all blog posts sorted by creation date
    client.getEntries({
      content_type: env.CTF_BLOG_POST_TYPE_ID,
      order: "sys.createdAt",
    }),
  ])
    .then(([entries]) => {
      // return data that should be available in the template
      return {
        posts: entries.items,
      }
    })
    .catch(console.error)
})
</script>
```